# Jpa orphanRemoval = true first delete?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have entities like below :

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {“user_member_id", “address_id”})
})
Public class User(){

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = “user”, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserMember> userMembers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = “user”, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Address> addresses;

    //… getters setters

    public void setRoles(List<UserMembers> userMembers) {
      this.userMembers.clear();

      List<UserMembers> userMembers = userMembers.stream()
                    .map(operatorRole -> new OperatorRoleMember(this, operatorRole))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
      this.roleMembers.addAll(roleMembers);
    }

}


@Entity
Public class UserMember(){

    private Long id;
    private name;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    //getters and setters...

}
```

When I run setRoles(List userMembers) in a transaction, it first try to insert new list members and then delete old data.

The problem is my table have unique constraint, old data and new data conflict with each other.

it would work fine If it first try to delete old ones and then insert new ones.
Is there  any solution for this situation?

Comment: migrate your database.

Comment: @K.Nicholas why ?

Comment: The old data won't work with the new schema = you need to "migrate the database". You need to do things like delete incompatible rows first before applying the index or copy to a new table or whatever will work.

Comment: @K.Nicholas There is no old schema and table also all data compatible, I just want to try bulk update. Delete existing userMembers for this user and add news. But orphan removel caused that first add new ones and then delete old ones. But it should run first delete and then add new ones for me.

Comment: so, what does "delete old data" mean? What old data? No old schema then no old data.

Comment: Please post the actual code of `setRoles`. It currently doesn't compile because `userMembers` is declared both as parameter and as local variable.
Also it copies the `roleMembers` onto itself, which might be an error in your posting or the actual problem you are having.

Comment: I got the same error and do not see a way but to use a workaround. In my case I can change my entities so that they don't violate the constraint. But if somebody finds a way so that hibernate deletes first and then inserts new ones, please let me know!